# A request to "drag" other pop-ups too

Tags: feature-request, popups

I think all guys have noticed that we can drag the "VTC" pop-up and flagging pop-up. But, this doesn't happen to many other pop-ups. For instance, let's take the "comment-flagging" or the "edit-rejection" pop-up. Even the comment-flagging popup can be ignored. But, It'd be really of help to many if "edit-rejection" and other pop-ups were also made the ability to drag.